# undefined local variable in render partial from create.js.erb

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I am getting an error in my firebug response when my create.js.erb executes.  Please see below.

## create.js.erb

```
<% if @document.new_record? %>
  alert("Failed to upload document: <%= j @document.errors.full_messages.join(', ').html_safe %>");
<% else %>
  $('#documents').append("<%= j render(:partial => "home/document", :document => @document) %>");
<% end %>
```

## Error

````
NameError at /documents
=======================

> undefined local variable or method `document' for #<#<Class:0x08d11700f0>:0x007f8dcb9bfc20>

app/views/home/_document.html.erb, line 2
-----------------------------------------

``` ruby
    1   <tr class="document_details file">
>   2       <td class="file_name"><%= link_to document.name, download_url(document) %></td>
    3       <td class="file_size"><%= number_to_human_size(document.file_size, :precision => 2) %></td>
    4       <td class="file_last_updated"><%= document.file_updated_at %></td>
    5       <td class="actions">
    6           <div class="download">
    7               <%= link_to "Download", download_url(document) %>
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
render(:partial => "home/document", :document => @document)
```

you should have:

```
render(:partial => "home/document", :locals => {:document => @document})
```

Comment: Or `render("home/document", :document => @document)`.

Comment: I noticed my post received negative votes, I would hate to have a post that is not useful.  How can I improve my post?

Comment: Still trying to understand why this was a bad question and voted down.  If anyone can explain, I would appreciate it.